# Two-way look-up in Excel with same values #REF Error

Tags: excel, match, vlookup, ref

I'm working on a scheduling project for excel.

I'm struggling with a #REF Error when I have more than one VLOOKUP and MATCH

[image]

On row 2, the numbers (04,05,06) are formatted as dates for 7/4/2016, 7/5/2016, etc

The table on row 9 (Table8) is where I am entering the dates.

The formula that works fine on B5 is

```
=IF(VLOOKUP(A3,Table8[[#All],[Name]:[Date]],MATCH(B2,Table8[[#All],[Date]],0),FALSE)=B2,"OFFr","")
```

A simple copy and paste for C5.. but returns a #REF error

```
=IF(VLOOKUP(A3,Table8[[#All],[Name]:[Date]],MATCH(C2,Table8[[#All],[Date]],0),FALSE)=C2,"OFFr","")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your [VLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65) is not doing what you think it is. It works in B5 by coincidence that the second row (2) provides the second column in the VLOOKUP's *column_num* parameter.

Use the [AGGREGATE¹ function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) for the matching date.

```
=IFERROR(IF(AGGREGATE(15, 6, Table8[date]/((Table8[name]=$A3)*(Table8[date]=B$2)), 1)=B$2, "OFFr"), "")
```

[image: AGGREGATE two column match]

If your Excel is pre-2010 or you need to provide backwards compatibility, there are other two column match formulas available.

Pre-xl2010 two-column-match:

```
=IFERROR(IF(INDEX(Table8[date],MAX(INDEX((ROW(Table8[name])-ROW(Table8[[#Headers],[name]]))*(Table8[name]=$A3)*(Table8[date]=B$2), , )))=B$2, "OFFr"), "")
```

¹ <sub>The [AGGREGATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) was introduced with Excel 2010. It is not available in earlier versions.</sub>

Comment: Thank you! Worked like a charm

Comment: No worries. I've added a pre-xl2010 solution if you ever need it.